# Verify API Gateway client certificate in ELB

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb, client-certificates

I want to proxy API Gateway requests to a container in an ECS cluster. As API Gateway can not be placed in a security group, I have to expose the service through an internet-facing ALB load balancer. To verify that the service only handles traffic from API GW, I'm looking to use [client certificates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html).

Is there a way to have ELB verify the API Gateway client certificate for me and terminate the SSL connection before handing the request off to my HTTP backend?

If ELB cannot verify the certificate, it seems to me that I have to "downgrade" the proxy to a TCP proxy, and perform the SSL handshake in my service. However, to do this, I also need to serve the certificate from the service. This is a problem because I'm using AWS provisioned SSL certificates, and I do not possess the private key. Thus I would have to not only recreate the SSL handshake, but also get my SSL certificate from somewhere else, is this correct?

Hoping there's a low-effort way to set up the trust between API Gateway and an ECS service behind an ALB.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing use of abbreviations - I am using `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer`, not the old one. This is what I'm referring to as "ELB", which I guess should more appropriately be "ALB"?

Comment: did you find a solution for this question?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, ELB does not support validating the client certificate for you. You can implement SSL termination on your service and use the ELB in TCP mode (or use the newer NLB). You don't need the private key of the client certificate, you simply add the public key/cert to your trusted CA on the service so that the service only trusts the API GW client certificate.

Comment: Jack, do you know if AWS PrivateLink can be applicable here to "establish" trust? also, one more question on trust establishment (although not related to certificates) - is there a way to configure integration backend to http hosted on EC2 which is locked down within VPC (without public IP address)?

Comment: The private key I'm talking about is for the SSL certificate, not the client certificate. In order to verify the certificate, I have to pipe traffic through an NLB, but then the service needs to serve up an SSL certificate, right? And I can't use the AWS provisioned one that we're currently using to terminate SSL on the ALB, because I can't get its private key. Maybe (hopefully) I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: Ah. Well as you may have seen, VPC Link is now available in API GW which would allow you to secure your backend connection without client auth SSL.

Comment: VPC link is still a poor solution, because you end up with your backends exposed to your entire VPC. You still need client cert auth or similar to enforce that the traffic is coming via API Gateway, and not bypassing authentication.